Why do passive materials impact magnetic field?
When calibrating magnetometers you need to consider the soft-iron distortions, from my understanding they are basically passive materials that deform the magnetic field.
I'm curious why these passive materials impact the field since they don't produce a magnetic field on their own?

This question is similar to: Why do ferromagnetic materials channel magnetic field lines?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A refrigerator magnet is a 'passive material' that certain would distort a magnetometer reading as well.

By "passive materials" I assume you mean paramagnetic materials. Although these materials will not support their own intrinsic magnetic field, they will still react to an external magnetic field by creating an induced field that is aligned with the external field. The induced field is due to the presence of unpaired electrons in the material, which align the direction of their spin with the external field. This induced field then affects the apparent strength and direction of the external field.
There are also diamagnetic materials, in which the induced field opposes the external field, but diamagnetic materials have a much smaller effect on the external field than paramagnetic materials.
